# Unexpected end of command aleatório no firebird

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

Estou tendo um problema no sistema que desenvolvo, por algum motivo recebo a mensagem:

> Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 214

Mas não encontro qual *SQL* está ocorrendo o problema. Pelo que achei na internet, geralmente se trata de problemas com uso de *procedures* ou *SQLs* executados em blocos, mas no meu caso não utilizo nenhum dos dois. Existe uma maneira de identificar qual é esse *SQL* problemático via *Firebird* ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Em qual momento ocorre o erro? Qual o comando que foi executado antes da ocorrência do erro?

Comment: O erro ocorre em alguma função especifica ? Pelo que me lembro (nem mais instalado tenho ...) um Query1.SQL.SaveToFile(´C:PastaArquivo.Txt´) salva o sql num arquivo , daí execute isto remotamente

Comment: Esse é o problema que estou tentando identificar, não consegui pegar em qual SQL que está ocorrendo esse problema, eu fiz uma vasculha nos fontes para verificar qual SQL, mas não achei.

Comment: try...except... captura o erro cara, coloca para salvar o sql executado

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem ?

Você poderia postar o SQL que ajudaria muito.

Uma das técnicas que uso em casos desse tipo :

**1** - Query.Savetofile('C:\sql.sql') -- Para obter o SQL e rodar a query para identificar o problema.

**2** - Ou usar Try excepet para capturar o erro.

**3** - Delphi Options >Debugger Option > Embarcadero Debugge> Language Exception, desmarca as opções que está em "Exception types ton ignore ".

**4** - Quando der o erro clica em Break.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: o grande problema é que eu não sei exatamente qual SQL que gera o erro, só acontece em produção

Comment: Você precisa mapear passo a passo, para reproduzir o problema. Exemplo verificar se é na geração de algum relatório, ou se é ao abrir a tela, se for ao fazer a pesquisa. 

Para poder te ajudar você poderia dizer em qual passo no seu sistema  ocorre o erro. em qual tela ...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar colocar um break point no evento que gera o erro, por exemplo, no click do botão, e vai dando steps, até chegar na linha que da o erro, feito isto poste novamente, vai dar pra ter uma ideia melhor... pode ser comando sql gerado pelo componente, como tambem pode ser algum problema na concatenação de comandos em tempo de execução, onde, olhando tudo parece bem, mas executando o script montado se torna problematico. fico no seu aguardo

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.

Comment: O problema em questão é que ocorre isso em produção, na máquina de um cliente aparentemente. Eu tentei fazer isso localmente, na minha máquina e meu ambiente, e não ocorre isso